# Apply CSS Animation on a Particular Element, NOT on its Children

Tags: css

I have a CSS class for flickering animation and can't find a way to not apply it on child buttons inside.

Tried animation: none !importnant but had no luck.

```css
@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.useBliinker {
  border: 0.1em dashed #ff6a00;
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

.useBliinker>button {
  animation: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="useBliinker">
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?  It may be possible to amend the selector to only target the part you wish to animate.

Comment: You can't exclude children from an animation, since you're animating their container as a whole; it's the same as `opacity`, etc.

Comment: What are you going to animate in an element if not its children? Every `div` consists of its children and nothing else -- there is nothing to animate if not that. Can you imagine animating an aspect of an element, such as its opacity, but not of its children? What will it look like?

Comment: @amn div can have (flickering) border

Comment: Then I advise you to update the question and describe your exact problem, because in general the question does not seem to apply, yet there may be some cases where it may apply for things like borders.

Comment: What about colored background with animation? After reading BenM's pseudo-element solution, I now think it may be applicable to other situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't exclude children from an animation, since you're animating their container as a whole; it's the same as `opacity`, etc.

You can just animate the `border-color` instead:

```css
@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    border-color: #ff6a00;
  }
}

.useBliinker {
  border: 0.1em dashed transparent;
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="useBliinker">
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can also animate a psuedo-element instead:

```css
@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.useBliinker {  
  padding: .1em;
  position: relative;
}
.useBliinker::after {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
  border: .1em dashed #ff6a00;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="useBliinker">
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can only do it with border

```css
@keyframes btnBorder {
  50% {
    border-color:transparent;
  }
}

.useBliinker {  
  padding: .1em;
  animation: btnBorder 1s linear infinite;
  border: .1em dashed #ff6a00;
}
```

```html
<div class="useBliinker">
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```